# Does the connection variable from the __construct need to be inserted in a mysqli_query?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm starting to make a PHP class for a database connection, i've made a constructor and in that constructor i make the connection to the database.

```
class mysqli_db{

        function __construct()
        {
            $conn = mysqli_connect("ip","username","password");

            if (!$conn) {
                echo "Cannot connect to server";
                exit();
            }

            $db = mysqli_select_db($conn,"silvaag166_prj");

            if (!$db) {
                echo "Cannot select database";
                exit();
            }
        }

    }
```

I understand de part above but now i want to make a function to select data from the database so i've made this:

```
public function selectAll($tablename)
        {
            return mysqli_query(?,"SELECT * FROM ".$tableName);
        }
```

At the ? i need to add the connection string and that can be found in the constructor. How do i need to insert the connectionstring at the ?.

Comment: `return mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM ".$tableName);` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii-So the $conn can be accesed in the whole class?

Comment: declare it outside.then you can access `$this->conn`

Comment: Can you give an example @FastSnail

Comment: @Matt i am using `mysqli_delect_db`

Comment: @CollinKoornstra https://ghostbin.com/paste/6587p .you are using procedural style to connect db you can use oop

Comment: @FastSnail Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the connection as a class property, it will then be available to the whole class i.e. all its methods as `$this->conn`

```
class mysqli_db{
    private $conn;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect("ip","username","password");

        if (!$this->conn) {
            echo "Cannot connect to server";
            exit();
        }

        $db = mysqli_select_db($this->conn,"silvaag166_prj");

        if (!$db) {
            echo "Cannot select database";
            exit();
        }
    }

    public function selectAll($tablename)
    {
        return mysqli_query($this->conn,"SELECT * FROM ".$tableName);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was writing in my answer. You are split second faster than me. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$this->conn`

```
class mysqli_db{
    private $conn;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect("ip","username","password");

        if (!$this->conn) {
            echo "Cannot connect to server";
            exit();
        }

        $db = mysqli_select_db($this->conn,"silvaag166_prj");

        if (!$db) {
            echo "Cannot select database";
            exit();
        }
    }

    public function selectAll($tablename)
    {
        return mysqli_query($this->conn,"SELECT * FROM ".$tableName);
    }

}
```